# How to replace the empty dropdown with "Please select" value in customer dropdown attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I have title dropdown in the registration form. I am using Magento Commerce edition, i used Magento customer attribute option from admin to create title drop down.
[image]

But the first value of dropdown coming empty.

How can i make empty option value as "Please select".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Html.

```
<select>
<option disabled selected>Please select</option>
...
</select>
```

Comment: HI @Wang Gang, thanks for your response. Could you please explain more detail.